# Need help on precalculus question utilizing $e^{i\pi}$. Question in the body

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Find all possible integer values of $n$ such that the following system of equations has a solution for $z$:
\begin{align*}
z^n &= 1, \\
\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)^n &= 1.
\end{align*}

I've been working on this problem for a few hours now and I haven't made much progress, does anyone have any ideas on how to progress and get an answer? $z$ is supposed to be a complex number in exponential form, so $e^{i\pi}$.

SIDENOTE: I'm a precalculus student.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Put $$z=re^{it}$$

$z $ is a root of the first equation if
$$r=1;\; \text{ and } \; t=\frac{2k\pi}{n}$$

or
$$z=e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}$$
thus $ z+\frac 1z $ is a real.
the same $ z $ satisfies the second equation if
$z+\frac 1z=1=2\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{n}) $

which gives

$$\frac{2k\pi}{n}=\pm \frac{\pi}{3}+2K\pi$$
and
$$n=\frac{6k}{\pm  1+6K}$$

$$\text{ or }$$

$z+\frac 1n=-1$ and $ n =2p$ even which gives

$$\frac{k\pi}{p}=\pm \frac{2\pi}{3}+2K\pi$$
and
$$n=\frac{3k}{\pm 2+3K}$$

we conclude that necessarily, $ n $ should be of the form $$n=6k, \;\;k\in \Bbb Z$$

Comment: Thank you! I just have a question about the variables, what are k and p?

Comment: @Alsagol $ k\in \Bbb Z$ and for the second solution $ z+1/z=-1$  , $n$ is even of the form $n=2p$.

Answer (score 1):

As $z+\frac1z$ is real and a root of unity you have $z+\frac1z=\pm1$ so $z^2\pm z+1=0$.  Multiplying by $z\mp1$, we get $z^3=\pm1$ so in one case $z$ is a primitive 3rd root of unity and in the other $z$ is a primitive 6th root of unity.  Thus it is necessary and sufficient for $n$ to be a multiple of 3.